# Just installed Ubuntu 12.04, not sure if I did it right

Tags: 12.04, grub2

My dual boot installation of Ubuntu crashed a few days ago, and I re-installed it from scratch while getting rid of the dual boot. I've had issues in the past, so I'm nervous about the "quality" of my installation - I let the auto installer do it for me this time. My gparted looks like this:

[image: a busy cat]

Is this correct/optimal? I had the "unknown partition, grub rescue" prompt after my installation, so I created the bios_grub partition as seen below and things seem to be working for now. But if history repeats itself, I'll be troubleshooting in a few months.

Comment: ubuntu us usually a work in progress so troubleshooting is likely :P but as for your disk, what exactly did you do to the harddrive before reinstalling? did you do a deep format and got rid of EVERY partition? or is that fat32 still a windows boot partition?

Comment: I let the auto installer get rid of everything and handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that won't get rid of some partitions as we see here. If the system is working fine I wouldn't worry too much. The only way to be 100% safe would be for you to boot from the ubuntu installer again, do a deep format of the hard drive, and then reinstall ubuntu on it with the normal installer. Then you'll be sure that only ubuntu is left and everything in there is as it's supposed to be. Not that you won't run into problems in the future but you will certainly not run into weird partition-related issues or lingering data interfering somehow.

Comment: I guess that's somewhat comforting. I love Ubuntu, but I've had to re-install or troubleshoot multiple times in the past month and a half alone. It's pretty frustrating, especially when I hear about devs who use Ubuntu every day and never have these problems.

Comment: Not having problems in ubuntu is a lie. We all have problems. It's the speed and ability to fix them that you get better at over time :P